# Using a series expansion, determine the value of the following integral with an error less than $10^{-8}$: $\int_0^{0.1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3 + 1}}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, power-series

Using a series expansion, determine the value of the following integral with an error less than $10^{-8}$.

$$\int_0^{0.1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3 + 1}}$$

Let $f(x) = 1/(x^3 + 1)$. I know that $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n x^{3n}$$
How do I find the series of $1/\sqrt{x^3 + 1}$ ? This done, how can I determine the integral with the required error? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You use Taylor's theorem, taking successive derivatives of $\frac 1{\sqrt {x^3+1}}$ and evaluating them at $0$ to get the series.  The error term lets you bound the error of the integral.

Comment: For the series in the integrand, you can Newton’s binomial expansion $$(1+u)^p = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{p}{n} u^p$$ with $p=-\tfrac12$ and $u=x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

The integrand is still a binomial series, but with exponent $-\frac12$. Thus you can approximate the integrand as $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-1/2}nx^{3n}=1-\frac12x^3+\frac38x^6-\frac5{32}\xi^9,0\le\xi\le0.1.$$ In particular, you can now bound the integrand as $$1-\frac12x^3+\frac38x^6-\frac5{32}x^9 \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+1}} \le 1-\frac12x^3+\frac38x^6$$

Integrating the first three terms gives
$$\int_0^{0.1}\left(1-\frac12x^3+\frac38x^6\right)\,dx=\left[x-\frac18x^4+\frac3{56}x^7\right]_0^{0.1}=10^{-1}-\frac1810^{-4}+\frac3{56}10^{-7},$$
while the error term in the lower bound integrates to $$\left[ -\frac{1}{64} x^{10} \right]_0^{0.1} = -\frac{1}{64}10^{-10},$$
which is clearly less than $10^{-8}$.